# Azure Function not being immediately triggered as expected

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

We have an Azure function that is supposed to run as soon as a file is inserted into one of our Azure Storage blobs.  We are seeing that it actually takes anywhere from 1-10 minutes to run after the file appears in the storage blob.  We can't confirm for sure, but it appears that it's polling the storage blob every 10 minutes looking for changes, instead of running instantly upon insert.

Here is the code for the Trigger; the `order-requests` blob is the one where the file gets inserted:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;


namespace Integration
{
    public static class IntegrationFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("AbcIntegration")]
        public static async Task Run(
            [BlobTrigger("order-requests/{name}", Connection = "BlobStorageConString")] CloudBlockBlob blob, 
            [Blob("order-responses/{name}")] CloudBlockBlob outputBlob,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var result = await new IntegrationService().IntegrateTask(blob, outputBlob);



            log.LogInformation(result);
        }
    }
}
```

How can we ensure the function runs the instant the file hits the blob?

Answer (score 4):

After doing some research, there are two options to address this:

1. Use Event Grid triggering instead of Blob triggering: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid?tabs=csharp
2. Ensure the function app is on an App Service Plan (not a Consumption Plan) and make sure the App is set to Always On.

Implementing #2 is what worked for us.  We were on a Consumption Plan, which can take up to 10 minutes to fire-off a trigger for a Function App.  We switched the app to an App Service Plan, set it to Always On, and now we are getting immediate execution when a file hits the blob.

It's important to note that additional costs are involved with an Always On App Service Plan.  The idea behind a consumption plan is to only pay for when the function is running.  This comes at its own cost though of possible cold starts taking up to 10 minutes for executions to occur.

Comment: There is a cost associated with having an App Service Plan though, no? Depending on usage this may not be the most cost effective method. I'm not sure what types of costs are associated with Event Grid triggering.

Comment: @billoverton you are correct.  An always-on App Service plan is more costly than a Consumption Plan.  I will add this to my answer.

Comment: Hi @Stpete111. It's great that you've found an answer to your question. So, don't hesitate to [accept as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so the others who have the same problem, could easily find and use this solution

Comment: @JustShadow I definitely will, but it says I have to wait til tomorrow to do so.